# ROS Tutorials PDF

Tags: ros, tutorial, print, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a PDF file hosted anywhere for the ROS beginner tutorials?

I would like to print them out to work from and make notes, but would like to avoid printing each page individually if possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106666/ros-tutorials-pdf/) by [Craig Hay](https://answers.ros.org/users/9446/craig-hay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki pages are the primary sources for tutorials and documentation. There is a pdf exporter plugin which is available in the menu bar at the right for each page.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0